# Implementation of Vector Clocks

Tags: java, frameworks, reference-implementation, vector-clock

For my code which is running on different devices, i need to determine the ordering of messages which are sent between those devices. Therefore I would like to use vector clocks since I read vector clocks allow for the ordering of events.

Is there any established framework/public API which I can use for that? Or a reference implementation= Or do I have to code it from scratch?

Thanks for any references and hints

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939633/is-there-an-off-the-shelf-clock-synchronization-solution-for-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `VectorClock` implementation is available from [Google Code](http://tud-in4150-fp-ass2b.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/in4150/mutex/VectorClock.java).

You could also look at the patches to add vector clock support in [Cassandra](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-580).

You should also read the wiki [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) [[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_vector) for limitations of the technique and other alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

I found this vector clock written in Java as a part of [project voldemort](http://github.com/voldemort/voldemort).

Here's a link to the [source code](https://github.com/voldemort/voldemort/blob/master/src/java/voldemort/versioning/VectorClock.java).  You'll need to also pull down the class and interface references.

Here's a link to the [Javadoc](http://project-voldemort.com/javadoc/all/voldemort/versioning/VectorClock.html).

Here's a Wikipedia article on [vector clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock).